# React: Query, delay useReducer

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I've been scratching my head around this one for quite some time now, but I'm still not sure what to do.

Basically, I'm pulling data from a database via useQuery, which all works well and dandy, but I'm also trying to use `useReducer` (which I'm still not 100% familiar with) to save the `initial data` as the `state` so as to detect if any changes have been made.

**The problem:**

While the useQuery is busy fetching the data, the `initial data` is `undefined`; and that's what's being saved as the `state`. This causes all sorts of problems with regards to validation amd saving, etc.

Here's my main form function:

```
function UserAccountDataForm({userId}) {
    const { query: {data: userData, isLoading: isLoadingUserData} } = useUserData(userId);
    
    const rows = React.useMemo(() => {
        if (userData) { /* Process userData here into arrays */ }
        return [];
    }, [isLoadingUserData, userData]); // Watches for changes in these values

    const { isDirty, methods } = useUserDataForm(handleSubmit, userData);
    const { submit, /* updateFunctions here */ } = methods;

    if (isLoadingUserData) { return <AccordionSkeleton /> } // Tried putting this above useUserDataForm, causes issues

    return (
        <>
            Render stuff here
            *isDirty* is used to detect if changes have been made, and enables "Update Button"
        </>
    )
}
```

Here's useUserData (responsible for pulling data from the DB):

```
export function useUserData(user_id, column = "data") {
    const query = useQuery({
        queryKey: ["user_data", user_id],
        queryFn: () => getUserData(user_id, column), // calls async function for getting stuff from DB
        staleTime: Infinity,
    });
}

return { query }
```

And here's the reducer:

```
function userDataFormReducer(state, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "currency":
            return {... state, currency: action.currency} 
// returns data in the same format as initial data, with updated currency. Of course if state is undefined, formatting all goes to heck
        default:
            return;
    }
}

function useUserDataForm(handleSubmit, userData) {
    const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(userDataFormReducer, userData);
    console.log(state) // Sometimes this returns the data as passed; most of the times, it's undefined.
    const isDirty = JSON.stringify(userData) !== JSON.stringify(state); // Which means this is almost always true.

    const updateFunction = (type, value) => { // sample only
        dispatch({type: type, value: value});
    }
}

export { useUserDataForm };
```

Compounding the issue is that it doesn't always happen. The main form resides in a `<Tab>`; if the user switches in and out of the tab, sometimes the `state` will have the proper `initial data` in it, and everything works as expected.

The quickest "fix" I can think of is to NOT set the `initial data` (by not calling the reducer) while useQuery is running. Unfortunately, I'm not sure this is [possible](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). Is there anything else I can try to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Compounding the issue is that it doesn't always happen. The main form resides in a ; if the user switches in and out of the tab, sometimes the state will have the proper initial data in it, and everything works as expected.

This is likely to be expected because `useQuery` will give you data back from the cache if it has it. So if you come back to your tab, `useQuery` will already have data and only do a background refetch. Since the `useReducer` is initiated when the component mounts, it can get the server data in these scenarios.

There are two ways to fix this:

1. Split the component that does the query and the one that has the local state (useReducer). Then, you can decide to only mount the component that has useReducer once the query has data already. Note that if you do that, you basically *opt out* of all the cool background-update features of react-query: Any additional fetches that might yield new data will just *not* be "copied" over. That is why I suggest that IF you do that, you turn off the query to avoid needless fetches. Simple example:

```
const App = () => {
 const { data } = useQuery(key, fn)

 if (!data) return 'Loading...'
 
 return <Form data={data} />

}

const Form = ({ data }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(userDataFormReducer, data)

}
```

since the reducer is only mounted when data is available, you won't have that problem.

2. Do not copy server state anywhere :) I like this approach a lot better because it keeps server and client state separate and also works very well with useReducer. Here is an example [from my blog](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/use-state-vs-use-reducer#passing-props-to-reducers) on how to achieve that:

```
const reducer = (amount) => (state, action) => {
  switch (action) {
    case 'increment':
      return state + amount
    case 'decrement':
      return state - amount
  }
}

const useCounterState = () => {
  const { data } = useQuery(['amount'], fetchAmount)
  return React.useReducer(reducer(data ?? 1), 0)
}

function App() {
  const [count, dispatch] = useCounterState()

  return (
    <div>
      Count: {count}
      <button onClick={() => dispatch('increment')}>Increment</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch('decrement')}>Decrement</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

If that works is totally dependent on what your reducer is trying to achieve, but it could look like this:

```
const App = () => {
 const { data } = useQuery(key, fn)
 const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(userDataFormReducer)
 const currency = state.currency ?? data.currency
}
```

By keeping server state and client state separately, you'll only store what the user has chosen. The "default values" like currency stay out of the state, as it would essentially be state duplication. If the currency is undefined, you can still choose to display the server state thanks to the `??` operator.

Another advantage is that the dirty check is relatively easy (is my client state undefined?) and resets to the initial state also just mean to set the client state back to undefined.

So the actual state is essentially a computed state from what you have from the server and what the user has input, giving precedence to the user input of course.